# Check_Mk RRD File Average Value Mismatch

Tags: rrdtool

I am trying to pull the data from the Check Mk server RRD File for CPU and Memory. From that, am trying to find the MAX and Average value for the particular Host for 1 month period. For the maximum value, I have fetched the file from the Check_mk server using the RRD fetch command and I get the exact value when I compared the output in the check_mk graph but when I try to do the same for the Average value I get the wrong output which does not match the Check_mk graph value and RRD File raw value. Kindly refer to the attached images where I have verified the value for average manually by fetching the data but it shows the wrong output.

[image]
[image]

Hello @Steve shipway,
Please find the requested data.

1)Structure of RRD File. Attached the image.

2)We are not generating the graph from the Check_mk . We are generating the RRD File using rrdtool dump CPU_utilization.xml > /tmp/CPU_utilization1.xml rrdtool fetch CPU_utilization_user.rrd MAX -r 6h -s Starting Date-e ending date.
Share

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NE2K.png)

Comment: Can you please add (1) the structure of your RRD file (using rrdtool info) and (2) the rrdtool commands you used to generate both the graph and the data dump you are processing.  Likely the reason is due to different summary methods but its impossible to tell without more information.  Remember that RRDTool is not a relational database, it summarises data on storage, so we need to know how you have configured the RRD.

Comment: Hello Steve, Requested data updated. Kindly check and do the needful.

Comment: For the RRD structure, I mean the configuration of the DSs and RRAs.  You get this using `rrdtool info`.  How is the graph being generated?  What is the `rrdtool graph` command being used?  Also, your rrdfetch seems to be forced into a 6h resolution for some reason?  This is likely less than the resolution in your monthly graph, which would explain the different averages as the monthly data points (in the graph) would be averaged over larger intervals than the fetched ones (in the xml).

Comment: Also, confirm the exact rrdtool commands used for the graph and fetch, so that we can compare the time windows and data resolution

Comment: We are not generating the graph using command line we used to generate the graph using check_mk console via GUI method and we are taking 6h interval  for 1 month data for calculation so that the values will be less and easy to calculate if we want to try different intervals let me know will try the same  and the exact fetch command is rrdtool fetch CPU_utilization_user.rrd MAX -r 6h -s Starting Date-e ending date.

Comment: The `fetch` will give you the data held in the RRA but the graph may have implicit averaging of data points.  What gets averaged depends on which RRA are defined in your RRD, which I can't tell without the output of `rrdtool info`.  Maybe try a `fetch` over the same time window as the graph and then see if the averages match